# How to fix Valgrind memory leaks?

Tags: c++, debugging

I am trying to implement a basic Skip List but i can not figure out what the problem is because when I run it it gives me Segmentaion Fault.

I have used Valgrind to check the memory leaks and it gives me some DEFINITELY LOST BLOCKS errors.

I run Valgrind like so :

`valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all -v ./myProgram`

I have tried deleting what can be deleted, but it gives me the same result plus some other errors.

```
==20782== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20782==     in use at exit: 96 bytes in 2 blocks
==20782==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 12 frees, 81,976 bytes allocated
==20782== 
==20782== Searching for pointers to 2 not-freed blocks
==20782== Checked 111,288 bytes
==20782== 
==20782== 48 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==20782==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20782==    by 0x1096AA: SkipList<int>::insertID(int, int) (in /home/matei/Desktop/Anul 1/S.D./Tema1/checker_tema1_2019/tema1)
==20782==    by 0x109395: main (in /home/matei/Desktop/Anul 1/S.D./Tema1/checker_tema1_2019/tema1)
==20782== 
==20782== 48 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==20782==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20782==    by 0x1096CD: SkipList<int>::insertID(int, int) (in /home/matei/Desktop/Anul 1/S.D./Tema1/checker_tema1_2019/tema1)
==20782==    by 0x109395: main (in /home/matei/Desktop/Anul 1/S.D./Tema1/checker_tema1_2019/tema1)
==20782== 
==20782== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20782==    definitely lost: 96 bytes in 2 blocks
==20782==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20782==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20782==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20782==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20782== 
==20782== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==20782== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**SkipList.h**

```
using namespace std;

#define MIN_ID 0
#define MAX_ID 999999
#define NULL_SCORE 0

template < class T >
class Node {
public:
   T level;
   T ID;
   T score;
   Node<T>* next;
   Node<T>* prev;
   Node<T>* below;
   Node<T>* above;

   Node() {
      next = NULL;
      prev = NULL;
      below = NULL;
      above = NULL;
   }

   Node(T ID, T score) {
      this->level = 1;
      this->ID = ID;
      this->score = score;
      next = NULL;
      prev = NULL;
      below = NULL;
      above = NULL; 
   }

   Node(const Node& node) : level(node->level), ID(node->ID), score(node->score) {

   }

   Node& operator=(const Node& node) {
      level = node->level;
      ID = node->ID;
      score = node->score;
      return *this;
   }

   ~Node() {}

   T getScore() {
      return this->score;
   }

   T getID() {
      return this->ID;
   }

   T getLeve() {
      return this->level;
   }

   T setScore(T score) {
      T old_score;
      old_score = this->score;
      this->score = score;
      return old_score;
   }
};

template < class T >
class SkipList {
public:
   Node<T>* head;
   Node<T>* tail;
   Node<T>* p1;
   Node<T>* p2;
   T height;
   T no_entries;

   SkipList() {
      p1 = new Node<T>(MIN_ID, NULL_SCORE);
      p2 = new Node<T>(MAX_ID, NULL_SCORE);
      head = p1;
      tail = p2;
      p1->next = p2;
      p2->prev = p1;
      height = 1;
      no_entries = 0;
   }

   ~SkipList() {
      delete p1;
      delete p2;
   }

   SkipList(const SkipList& SkipList) : height(SkipList->height), no_entries(SkipList->no_entries) {

   }

   SkipList& operator=(const SkipList& SkipList) {
      height = SkipList->height;
      no_entries = SkipList->no_entries;
      return *this;
   }

   T getSize() {
      return this->no_entries;
   }

   T getHeight() {
      return this->height;
   }

   bool isEmpty() {
      if (no_entries == 0) {
         return true;
      }else {
         return false;
      }
   }

   T getScore(T ID) {
      Node<T>* p;
      p = searchID(ID);
      if (p.getID() == ID ) {
         return p->score;
      }else {
         return NULL;
      }
   }

   string coinFlip() {
      string s;
      string str1 = "Heads";
      string str2 = "Tails";
      int r;
      srand(time(0));
      for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
        r = 1 + (rand() %2);
      }
      if (r == 1) {
         s.assign(str1);
      }else if (r == 2) {
         s.assign(str2);
      }
      return s;
   }

   Node<T>* insertAbove(Node<T>* p, Node<T>* e, T ID, T score) {
      e = new Node<T>(ID, score);

      p->above = e;
      e->below = p;

      e->below->prev->above->next = e;
      e->prev = e->below->prev->above;

      e->below->next->above->prev = e;
      e->next = e->below->next->above;

      delete e;
      return e;

   }

   Node<T>* searchID(T ID) {
      Node<T>* p;
      p = head;
      while (p->below != NULL) {
         p = p->below;
         while (ID >= p->next->ID) {
            p = p->next;
         }
      }
      return p;
   }

   Node<T>* insertID(T ID, T score) {
      Node<T>* aux1;
      Node<T>* new_node1 = new Node<T>(ID, score);

      aux1 = searchID(ID);

      aux1->next = new_node1;
      new_node1->prev = aux1;
      new_node1->next = tail;

      while (coinFlip() == "Heads"); {
         if (new_node1->level >= height) {
            height++;
            Node<T>* new_node2 = new Node<T>(ID, score);

            //Create a new empty layer
            Node<T>* p1 = new Node<T>(MIN_ID, NULL_SCORE);
            Node<T>* p2 = new Node<T>(MAX_ID, NULL_SCORE);

            //Making the connections
            head->above = p1;
            tail->above = p2;

            p1->below = head;
            p2->below = tail;

            p1 = head;
            p2 = tail;

            while (aux1->above == NULL) {
               aux1 = aux1->prev;
            }
            aux1 = aux1->above;

            insertAbove(new_node1, new_node2, ID, score);

            new_node1->level++;
            delete new_node2;
         }
      }
      no_entries++;
      delete new_node1;
      return new_node1;
   }

   bool deleteID(T ID) {
      Node<T>* current = head;
      bool found = false;
      if (current->next == NULL && current->next->ID == ID) {
         found = true;
         current->next = current->next->next;
         no_entries--;
      }
      delete current;
      return found;
   }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include "SkipList.h"

using namespace std;
int main() {
   SkipList<int>* my_SkipList = new SkipList<int>();

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      my_SkipList->insertID(i, i);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use smart pointers.

Comment: @Quentin I cannot do that as it is a part of my homework and I am not alowed to use the features from STL  and I can only use a few of the libraries for C/C++

Comment: "STILL REACHABLE BLOCKS are not that harmful" - This may be true, but it shows that there's something happening in your code that you don't understand. This something, under different circumstances, may be harmful.

Comment: @BennyK So what can i do to fix my problem?Like, for example I am using the keyword  new in my Constructor twice and I am deleting those objects in Destructor, till here the same result but if I am deleting the same objects in Constructor, the errors/warnings from Valgrind go from 9 to 4 so what do I need to understand from that?

Comment: We need to see the code for that.

Comment: @BennyK I have edited my post, please consider that I am a begginer and just learning about this stuff. I hope that my code can tell you something.

Comment: Fix the segmentation fault before worrying about any memory leaks. If code that would have correctly cleaned up crashes, it likely just never got the chance to delete things.  Not necessarily the issue, but both your classes violate the Rule Of Three/Five.  Though at a glance I don't see anything copying them, so you could possibly just define the copy constructors and assignment as deleted, rather than implementing them.

Comment: Your destructors are never called because you don't delete the my_SkipList (which you shouldn't have newed in the first place btw, it makes no sense, you don't need a pointer to a list, just declare a list). However once you do cause its destructor to be called, you will discover that all your destructors are *wrong* and your program is very likely to crash. Finding out what's wrong with them is a very useful exercise.

Comment: @Quentin bad advice in this case. A linked (moreso doubly linked) list with smart pointers is not at all straightforward. I would even say it's pretty much impossible.

Comment: @n.m. sounds pretty possible to me. And if it weren't, well that'd be a good argument for not teaching C++ by implementing one of the odd objects that don't conform to the language's cleanup rules ;)

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, I have fixed some of the errors and now I get just 2 of them also regarding the use of the keyword new but if I am deleting them it gives me like 10+ errors in addition to the first 2/ and I have edited the post with the new code and the new errors. Thanks again!

Comment: @Quentin so try to implement it. Make sure you can create and destroy a list with 2^30 entries. No implementation of std::list I know uses smart pointers inside, I wonder why... C++ smart pointers are not end all and be all of memory management.

Comment: If you have new code, either [edit] and update your question with new code (and new error messages) or ask a new question.

Comment: @n.m. I have done what you said, sorry for the inconvenience, I am new to the rules of this site as I am with programming

Comment: Your destructors are still wrong. How many nodes do you allocate? (Find every place where a node is allocated, count how many times each one is executed) How many nodes do you destroy? (Find every place where a node is destroyed, count how many times each one is executed). Use a debugger or add debugging print statements.

Comment: Google "c++ rule of three".  Avoid testing this with too much data that you can't unravel, you must first debug this by making it work with 0, 1 and 2 nodes.

Comment: @n.m. I guess you're thinking about a stack overflow from the destructor or something. I still stand by my point: smart pointers *do* fit almost all resource management cases, and should be the first choice, especially while learning. Optimizing the hell out of a linked list or implementing some kind of oddball resource management case is out of a beginner's reach anyway.

Comment: @Quentin This is not even optimising. This is working code vs broken code. And it is logically incorrect. A node doesn't *own* the next node. Oh, and linked lists should not be taught to beginners at all. They have almost no uss in real world applications, and when they do, you do want to optimise the living hell out of them.

Comment: @n.m. That reasoning would make all recursive functions (non-terminal ones at least) "broken" by design. In any case I agree that a library-grade linked list should use manual memory management, but a list where each node owns its descendants doesn't shock me either. Learning C++ by trying to implement that weird indirect-ownership behaviour before learning about the normal case, however, strikes me as highly counterproductive.

Comment: @Quentin incorrect. O(n) recursion depth is not at all the same as O(log n) recursion depth. The former is broken, the latter is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I assume you added the `delete my_SkipList` at the end of `main`.)

If you compile with debug information, best without optimization (options depend on compiler, often `-g -O0`), `valgrind` shows the line numbers of detected problems, like

```
==23956== 48 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==23956==    at 0x4C266E7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23956==    by 0x400E94: SkipList<int>::insertID(int, int) (SkipList.h:194)
==23956==    by 0x400C40: main (main.cpp:13)
==23956== 
==23956== 48 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==23956==    at 0x4C266E7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23956==    by 0x400EB7: SkipList<int>::insertID(int, int) (SkipList.h:195)
==23956==    by 0x400C40: main (main.cpp:13)
```

From that we can easily see that the unmatched allocations are

```
            //Create a new empty layer
            Node<T>* p1 = new Node<T>(MIN_ID, NULL_SCORE);
            Node<T>* p2 = new Node<T>(MAX_ID, NULL_SCORE);
```

From here we can work out where there are related errors.

1. You must not `delete` nodes which are part of the existing `SkipList`, i. e. the `delete e` from `insertAbove()` and the `delete new_node1` from `insertID()` are to be removed.
2. In `insertID()` the code to insert `new_node1`

   ```
         aux1->next = new_node1;
         new_node1->prev = aux1;
         new_node1->next = tail;
   ```

   is wrong in assuming that the next node always were `tail`; better:

   ```
         new_node1->next = aux1->next; // next isn't necessarily tail
         aux1->next = new_node1;
         new_node1->prev = aux1;
   ```
3. Above all, the destructor `~SkipList()` only freeing the two nodes allocated in the constructor isn't sufficing - rather also all nodes allocated later for the `SkipList` have to be freed, e. g.:

   ```
      ~SkipList()
      {
           for (Node<T> *p, *c; p = head; )
           {
               head = head->above;
               do c = p, p = p->next, delete c; while (p);
           }
      }
   ```

Note that these points only resolve the allocation errors in the code, not any other logical error.